# How can I store user and pass in the same dict instead of a new empty dict?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to store multiple username and passwords in the same dictionary instead of starting an empty dictionary. My code right now can ask for the username and password five times, but it only stores each input separately instead of in the same dictionary.

```
def store(username, password):
    data = {}
    data[username] = password
    print data

def create():
    for i in range(5):
        user = raw_input("Username: ")
        pas = raw_input("Password: ")
        store(user, pas)
```

My output is as so:

```
Username: panda
Password: pandas
{'panda': 'pandas'}
Username: pan
Password: sauce
{'pan': 'sauce'}
Username: hi
Password: name
{'hi': 'name'}
Username: why
Password: so
{'why': 'so'}
```

All the 5 usernames and passwords don't store in the same dictionary, but a new dictionary is created. I want the output to add new user and password to previous user and password.

Comment: ...don't keep creating an empty dictionary?

Comment: Obligatory "I hope you're not using this approach for a real application" comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of a `dict` is to allow data values to be retrieved against more-or-less arbitrary keys (there are some limits, but they needn't concern a beginner).

So you would be better with a single `dict` whose keys are the user names and whose corresponding values are the associated passwords.

The function can take an existing dict and return a new one, in which case your calling sequence would be something like

```
pwdict = store(pwdict, user, pass)
```

but since the `dict`1 is a mutable structure you can also mutate it in place. The `dict` could be global to your function, but it makes more sense (i.e. it will give your program better coupling) to pass it explicitly as an argument to the store function. That way the reader sees by reading the call an explicit reference to the object.

So your code would then look more like this:

```
passwords = {}

def store(pdict, username, password):
    pdict[username] = password

def create():
    for i in range(5):
        user = raw_input("Username: ")
        pas = raw_input("Password: ")
        store(passwords, user, pas)

create()

print passwords
```

Here's a typical run:

```
Username: steve
Password: stevepw
Username: fred
Password: fredpw
Username: me
Password: mepw
Username: you
Password: youpw
Username: them
Password: thempw
{'steve': 'stevepw', 'me': 'mepw', 'you': 'youpw', 'them': 'thempw', 'fred': 'fredpw'}
```

Of course this makes it very apparent that Python's high-level operations do make such low-level functionality as storing another value in a dict rather over-specified. The call

```
store(passwords, user, pas)
```

would be better replaced by the statement inside the function body, and written as

```
passwords[user] = pas
```

which is both shorter and more direct, meaning that the reader doesn't have to refer to anything else to understand what's going on. Then the function is redundant and your code is shorter so there's less to go wrong!

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new `dict` instance every time you make a call to the `store` function.

Since functions are also objects, you could instead create a dict `data` as an attribute of the function `store` and use it to store the `username` and `password`.

Create one by using either one of the below methods :

By using the `setattr` function :

```
if not store.__dict__.has_key("data"):
    setattr(store, "data", dict())
```

Or by directly accessing the `store`'s `__dict__`

```
if not store.__dict__.has_key("data"):
    store.__dict__["data"] = dict()
```

You access the `data` as a member of the store.

```
store.data[username] = password
```

This is pythonic equivalent of a static variable inside the function.

**In essence your code will look like this :**

```
def store(username, password):
    # Create a 
    if not store.__dict__.has_key("data"):
        store.__dict__["data"] = dict()

    store.data[username] = password
    print store.data
    print id(store.data) # <--- Verify that the same dictionary object is being used again.
```

You will be able to verify that the same `dict` object is being used by printing out the `id` of the `store.data`.

As long as usernames are unique every time `store` function is called a new key, value pair is added to the `store.data` which can be accessed outside the function as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your dictionary in the create() routine, outside of the store() routine, and pass it in as an argument. Try:

```
def store(username, password, dict):
    dict[username] = password
    print dict

def create():
    myDict = {}
    for i in range(5):
        user = raw_input("Username: ")
        pas = raw_input("Password: ")
        store(user, pas, myDict)
```